# ffmpeg add video thumbnail only

Tags: ffmpeg

this code below am happy with it and now i wish to add a thumbnail to it using the 55.png without compromising the current code

```
ffmpeg -y -i 55.mp4 -loop 1 -framerate 30000/1001 -t 5 -i 55.png -t 0.5 -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 -filter_complex "[0:a]atempo=1.0,pan=stereo|c0<c0+0*c1|c1<c0+0*c1,aeval=val(0)|-val(1) [amain]; [0:v]setpts=PTS/1.0,crop=iw/1.2:ih/1.2,scale=1280:720,setdar=16/9 [vmain]; [1:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[vintro]; [vintro][2][vmain][amain]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 60 -b:v 1400k -profile:v main -level 3.1 -acodec libmp3lame -ab 128k -ar 7350 -metadata title="" -metadata artist="" -metadata album_artist="" -metadata album="" -metadata date="" -metadata track="" -metadata genre="" -metadata publisher="" -metadata encoded_by="" -metadata copyright="" -metadata composer="" -metadata performer="" -metadata TIT1="" -metadata TIT3="" -metadata disc="" -metadata TKEY="" -metadata TBPM="" -metadata language="eng" -metadata encoder="" -bufsize 500000k -threads 0 -preset superfast -acodec aac -strict experimental -ab 192k out2222.mp4
```

Comment: OK and how do i implement it to my current code as i try it fails and gives error this is the whole point am here.

Comment: Show the command you tried and the complete log.